# Is Hahn-Kolmogorov theorem a direct result of Carathéodory's extension theorem?

Tags: measure-theory

Both theorems assume the same condition and conclusion, except that

- [Hahn-Kolmogorov  theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn-Kolmogorov_theorem) extends a premeasure on a field of subsets to a measure on a sigma algebra generated by the field of subsets
- [Carathéodory's extension theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_extension_theorem) extends a premeasure on a ring of subsets to a measure on a sigma algebra generated by the ring of subsets.

Since a field of subsets is also a ring of subsets, is Hahn-Kolmogorov  theorem a direct result of Carathéodory's extension theorem?

Thanks!

Comment: Hahn-Kolmogorov could be seen as the small brother to Caratheodory, that is it is slightly more direct but for the price of requiring a little bit more assumptions and getting less further... Moreover, Caratheodory is sort of an upgrade of the idea of Hahn-Kolmogorov.

Comment: Does anyone know which paper(s) first introduced the Hahn-Kolmogorov Theoremm?

Comment: Some authors (eg. Yeh) call the extension theorem the Hopf extension theorem. It's very unclear to me who first proved it what. I would guess Caratheodory was the first to prove the "outer measure restricts to a measure on the sigma-algebra of measurable sets" part. But textbook authors variously attach the names Caratheodory, Hahn, Kolmogorov, Hopf, Frechet to the part of the theorem about extending a premeasure on an algebra (or ring or semi-algebra or semi-ring) and to the part about uniqueness in the sigma-finite case.

Comment: @user109871 In the notes section of Chapter 1 of Folland's book, he clarifies who proved what and when. References are included too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It will depend, of course, on exactly how the theorems are stated. In his book [Introduction to Measure Theory](http://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/measure-book1.pdf), Tao states the  Carathéodory theorem first (1.7.3) but for outer measures, and then uses this to prove the Hahn-Kolmogorov theorem (1.7.8) for premeasures. However, as the proof to 1.7.8. shows, he has to do slightly more than just apply the  Carathéodory's extension theorem s he has stated it to obtain the second result.

As everyone knows, though, different authors often use the same name for different results. The Wikipedia articles seem to be particularly confusing about the difference between the two theorems. Perhaps the Wikipedia articles were written by different people who learned from different texts; that is always an issue with comparing different articles on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. As you said, the various versions of extension theorems all extend a premeasure on some family of subsets $\mathcal{F}$ of $\Omega$ to a measure on $\sigma(\mathcal{F})$, and differ in what conditions $\mathcal{F}$ satisfies.

1. The most general form of Carathéodory's extension theorem that I'm
   aware of requires $\mathcal{F}$ to be a **semi-ring**, i.e., (1). $\emptyset \in \mathcal{F}$, (2). $A, B \in \mathcal{F} \implies A \cap B \in \mathcal{F}$, and (3). $A, B \in \mathcal{F} \implies \exists n, \exists C_{1,2,...,n} \in \mathcal{F}, A - B = \dot\bigcup_i C_i$.  See, e.g., the [textbook](https://books.google.com/books?id=ez1bvgAACAAJ&pg=PA39) by Schilling, *"Measures, Integrals and Martingales"*.
2. The Wikipedia version of Carathéodory's extension theorem requires $\mathcal{F}$ to be a **ring**, i.e., (1). $\emptyset \in \mathcal{F}$, (2). $A, B \in \mathcal{F} \implies A \cup B \in \mathcal{F}$, and (3). $A, B \in \mathcal{F} \implies A - B \in \mathcal{F}$.
3. The Hahn-Kolmogorov theorem requires $\mathcal{F}$ to be a **field** (also called an algebra), i.e., (1). $\emptyset \in \mathcal{F}$, (2). $A, B \in \mathcal{F} \implies A \cup B \in \mathcal{F}$, and (3). $A \in \mathcal{F} \implies A^c \in \mathcal{F}$.  This seems to be the version used in the Ash and Dade textbook.

It's easy to show that a ring is closed under intersection (write $A \cap B = A - (A - B))$, and condition (3) for a semi-ring trivially holds or a ring, so a ring is a semi-ring. Also, it's clear that a field is a ring (that happens to also contain $\Omega$).

Therefore, version 1 ("Carathéodory's extension theorem") implies version 2 implies version 3 ("Hahn-Kolmogorov theorem").